Ensuring linear independence of Jordan chains
In my last question I falsely assumed that if we pick 2 linearly independent starting vectors, then the union of the generated Jordan chains are always linear independent. To illustrate my error, consider the following example: Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ The only eigenvalue is zero, and we have $\ker A = \text{span}(e_1,e_3)  $ and $\ker A^2 = \text{span}(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4).$ I construct 2 Jordan chains by selecting 2 linearly independent vectors $x=e_2$ and $y=e_4$ as starting vectors that are in $\ker A^2$ but not in $\ker A$ and apply $A$ on them. Then $(Ax,x)$ forms a Jordan chain and $(Ay,y)$ form another. The union of the chains is $(Ax,x,Ay,y)=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$, and $A$ has indeed the Jordan normal form with respect to this basis.
However, the selection of the starting vectors $x,y$ were arbitrary. If I instead picked $x=e_2,y=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, then they are still linearly independent, lie in $\ker A^2 \setminus \ker A,$ but $Ax=e_1=Ay$.
My question is whether or not a concrete strategy exists that can be applied when selecting starting vectors to ensure that the union of the generated Jordan chains is always linearly independent. Thank you.

This is true but it's the hardest step in the proof of the Jordan normal form theorem (at least the one using Jordan chains); arguably it is equivalent to the full theorem. Terence Tao does it here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/10/12/the-jordan-normal-form-and-the-euclidean-algorithm/
